# rpmbuild :error: Could not generate output filename for package myApp: unknown tag

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to build rpm and getting error :

```
rpmbuild :error: Could not generate output filename for package myApp: unknown tag
```

I tried to add a client name to a name of the rpm file . Before I inserted changes everything worked fine .

What I made in build.csh to get a client name :

```
 CLIENT=

 case:
 -c)CLIENT=$2
   shift 2
    ;;


rpmbuild -bb -vv \ 
   --define "client ${CLIENT}" \
   --define "_build_name_fmt %%{ARCH}/%%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}-%%{CLIENT}.%%{ARCH}.rpm" \
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The rpmbuild error is saying that one of your `%%{TAG}`'s is unknown.  In this case it is `%%{CLIENT}`

The `%%` are names that appear inside your spec file.  E.g.,

`Name: My_great_software`

`Version: 1.2.3`

To fix this you have 2 options.

Either define client inside of your spec file:

`Client: "client-name"`

Or use the shell variable in your rpmbuild command:

```
--define "_build_name_fmt %%{ARCH}/%%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}-$(CLIENT).%%{ARCH}.rpm"
```